# Page_Load of 2. user control never executes (website)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, data-binding, user-controls

I am in the process of making a website that displays information in boxes.
There will be different pages with different combinations of boxes. They will have a lot of boxes in common.
Therefor, I am making the boxes as user controls to then put on the different pages. The different pages will also share a master page.
However, when starting development of the 2. box, I ran into a problem:

The Page_Load (or the whole code behind) of the 1. box runs fine, but the Page_Load og the 2. box gets ignored. This results in a lot of null values that makes the aspx file crash.

My CT1.aspx contains this to use the two user controls:

```
<%@ Page Title="CustType1" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MTCustomer/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CT1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MTCustomer.CT1" %>

// Some HTML
    <td ID="column1" style="width: 400px;">
        <Box:CustomerInfoBoxAx runat="server" />
        <Box:CustomerInfoBoxMt runat="server" />
    </td>
// Some HTML
```

My Web.config contains this for the user controls to be usable:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="Box" tagName="InfoBoxA" src="~/Controls/InfoBoxA.ascx" />
    <add tagPrefix="Box" tagName="InfoBoxB" src="~/Controls/InfoBoxB.ascx" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

My user control A looks lige this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="InfoBoxA.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.InfoBoxA" %>

<% if (IsVisible("InfoBoxA") && Customer != null)
   { %>
    <div>
        <%-- Markup --%>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

And box B looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="InfoBoxB.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.InfoBoxB" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Styles/InfoBoxStyle.css")%>">

<% if (IsVisible("InfoBoxB") && Customer != null)
   { %>
    <div>
        <%-- Markup --%>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

I have tried to swap the order of the two user controls in the page.aspx, this also changed witch one had its Page_Load (or the whole code behind) ignored. Based on that, it looks like only the first code behind is executed, and the rest is ignored.

EDIT:
After following the exceptions that comes after the initial null reference exception, I can see that the Page.DataBind() in the first user control is still executing. This must mean that this is what causes the aspx file of both box one and two run. But how do I get around this?

Comment: Is there some kind of exception being thrown that prevents the second user control from being loaded? You might need to turn on additional exception watching in Visual Studio.

Comment: After turning on more exceptions, i discovered something more. Added edit to the buttom of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I removed `Page.DataBind()` from all user controls, and in the CT1.aspx.cs (the page code behind) i moved it from `Page_Load()` to `OnLoadComplete()`.

By doing this, `Page_Load()` in all files have been executed before the `Page.DataBind()` is executed.